# CSS: Sticky element on the bottom of horizontally scrolling container

Tags: html, css, sticky, sticky-footer

I am trying to make sticky footer inside of a horizontally scrolling element. I want that sticky footer to be aligned to the bottom, have auto height based on it's content and be as wide as scroll parent (in this example 200px), so when I scroll to the right, footer is on the same place and it's content is horizontally centered (content should be some element, not only a simple text). I would appreciate help.

Wanted solution:
[image: Wanted solution]

My current code:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.example {
  width: 200px;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: moccasin;
}

.footer {
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: palegreen;
  justify-self: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="example">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="footer">
      Footer
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: By sticky, does it start somewhere in the middle of the page? If it doesn't just make it `fixed` or `absolute`

Comment: yes, sticky is needed because this '.example' element will be placed somewhere in webpage like a component, so fixed or absolute position doesn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this solves your issue:
(Added Lorem Ipsum to show the scroll effect and footer being fixed)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.example {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: moccasin;
}

.footer {
  position: sticky;
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  top: 100%;
  background-color: palegreen;
  text-align: center;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="example">
  <div class="container">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
    survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
    software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum
    <div class="footer">
      Footer
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see the following changes. I changed some of your CSS on your `.footer` class to give it a 100% width and `position: relative` then I added `align-self: flex-end;` and some scroll bar styles using `::-webkit-scrollbar` feel free to change it around as desired.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.example {
  width: 200px;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-self: flex-end;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: moccasin;
}

.footer {
  position: relative;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: palegreen;
  align-self: flex-end;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 4px;
  height: 8px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: fixed;
  margin-left: 5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="example">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="footer"><p>Footer</p></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT:** You were using `justify-self: center;`. With a `position: relative;` you can use `align-self: flex-end;` to get the footer to display at the bottom. Also added `position: fixed;` with some margin to get your text to stay when scrolling.

Comment: thanks but this does not solve my problem.  'div.example' element will be placed somewhere in webpage like a component, so fixed or absolute position doesn't solve my problem. Also, your solution will make "Footer" text invisible when I scroll to the right. That's why I want to utilize sticky, footer text should be centered and visible all the time, even if container is scrolled to the right.

Comment: answer from @qUB3r-001 is the correct one and solves exactly what I wanted. Your solution with position: fixed will not work for me, because you are fixing footer to the viewport, it will not work in more complex page layout. Also, you are not centering footer content. Hard-coded margin-left will not work in reponsive environment, also, is not aware of dynamic content of the footer. I appreciate your help though.